# Why did all my gedit plugins croak on 13.10 (and how do I fix them)?

Tags: 13.10, gedit, plugins

I had a nice setup going on my old laptop. I was running gedit 3.4.1 on Ubuntu 12.04 with some nice plugins:

- ZenCoding
- GDP Completion
- GDP Format

Then my laptop died a splendid death and I bought a new laptop and installed 13.10 and started restoring my lovely plugin arrangement and they don't work. When I try to enable Zencoding or either of the GDP plugins I see an error:

> The plugin Zen Coding could not be loaded an error occurred: Plugin
>   loader 'python2' was not found

I've found instructions that suggest editing `~/.local/share/gedit/plugins/zencoding.plugin` to tweak the loader, but `python` is similarly "not found" and if I change it to `python3` the error changes to just "An error occurred: Failed to load"

How do I get these plugins working in gedit 3.8.3 on 13.10?

Answer (score 0):

Any plug-ins written in Python 2.x for GEdit, will need to be ported to work with Python 3.x, to work in GEdit on Ubuntu 13.10 or newer.

If they are from a package in the Ubuntu archive, you should file a bug against that package. If you are installing them from an upstream source into `~/.local/share/gedit/plugins/` then you should contact the upstream developers of the plug-ins to get them ported to Python 3.x.

I don't know of a specific guide to porting plug-ins for GEdit to Python 3.x, but any general guide to porting from Python 2.x to Python 3.x should help. Ideally, the plug-ins should work with either one, but the design of the plug-ins system used by GEdit and several other GNOME applications does not allow plug-in authors to do that easily. The `2to3` script should give some hints about what to change in the plug-in code, and the `python-six` library can be used for compatibility between both versions.

Comment: I don't suppose there are guidelines for that? It seems weird that the `gedit-developer-plugins` package installs plugins that don't work on the current system.

Comment: Is there a URL for the `2to3` script? Thanks.

Comment: No. `2to3` is part of the `python` package on Ubuntu.